# Highlight label when the field is focused

Tags: css

So I have a data-list field below where I want to also change the label colour when  the field is focused. What I've done below is I can't highlight the label when field is focused; it's the field only that is highlighted.

[image]

I have the css below:

```
<style lang="scss">
    .panel-con {
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
    }
    .group-list{
       input:focus { 
          border-color: #dbb100;
       }
    }
</style>
```

How can I make the labels' color the same as the fields color when the field is focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need

```
:focus-within
```

```css
.wrapper:focus-within p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <input class='input' type='text'/>
  <p>your text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work for microsoft browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within

Comment: @JonP Thanks for the heads-up :) But our application works and designed only for chrome so far; blocked in other browsers :)

Answer (score 2):

If your label is **before** your input/select in the DOM, you can't do it with just CSS alone. You'd need JS.

If your label is **after** your input/select in the DOM, you could do something like this. (I've created something similar to what you have shown)

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.wrapper select {
  display: block;
}
.wrapper select:focus {
  color: red;
}
.wrapper select:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
.wrapper label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<select name="example">
<option val="1">Option 1</option>
<option val="2">Option 2</option>
<option val="3">Option 3</option>
<option val="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<label for="example">Test Label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the output that I want is as answered by user3003238 :) Will change the color only on-focus, not on hover :)

Comment: Changed my answer and mine has 100% support on all browsers :)